# What is Residue of $f(z):=\dfrac{\sin z}{(z-\frac{\pi}{2})\cos z} $?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

$f(z):=\dfrac{\sin z}{(z-\frac{\pi}{2})\cos z} $

What is the residue of $f(z)$ at $z=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$?

My calculation is following.
\begin{align}
\lim_{z \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \left (z-\dfrac{\pi}{2} \right)^2 f(z) 
&=\lim_{z \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \left(z-\dfrac{\pi}{2} \right) \dfrac{\sin z}{\cos z} \\
&=_{l'Hospital's rule} \lim_{z\to \frac{\pi}{2}} \dfrac{\sin z + (z-\frac{\pi}{2})\cos z}{-\sin z}\\
&=-1.
\end{align}

Thus, $f$ has a pole of order $2$ at $z=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$.

Therefore,

\begin{align}
\text{Res}(f, \dfrac{\pi}{2})
&=\lim_{z\to \frac{\pi}{2} } \dfrac{d}{dz} \left(z-\dfrac{\pi}{2} \right)^2 f(z)\\
&=\lim_{z\to \frac{\pi}{2} } \dfrac{d}{dz} \left(z-\dfrac{\pi}{2} \right)\tan z \\
&=\lim_{z\to \frac{\pi}{2} } \Bigg( \tan z + \left(z-\dfrac{\pi}{2} \right) \dfrac{1}{\cos ^2 z} \Bigg)\\
&=\lim_{z\to \frac{\pi}{2} } \dfrac{\sin z \cos z + \left( z-\frac{\pi}{2} \right)}{\cos ^2 z}\\
&=_{l'Hospital's rule} \lim_{z\to \frac{\pi}{2} } \dfrac{\cos^2 z -\sin^2 z +1}{-2\cos z \sin z}\\
&= \lim_{z\to \frac{\pi}{2} } \dfrac{\cos^2 z -\sin^2 z +\sin^2 z + \cos^2 z}{-2\cos z \sin z}\\
&=\lim_{z\to \frac{\pi}{2} } \dfrac{2\cos^2 z}{-2\cos z \sin z}\\
&=\lim_{z\to \frac{\pi}{2} } \left(-\dfrac{\cos z}{\sin z }\right)\\
&=0.
\end{align}
I'm not sure if this is correct.
I would like you to tell me if this is correct or not.

Comment: Yes, it is. You can also calculate the series expansion of $f(z)=\sum_n a_n z^n$ and look for the term $a_{-1}$.

Comment: Substituting $x=z+\frac\pi2$ one immediatly obtains that $f(x)$ is an even  function of $x$ and thus its residue at $x=0$ is $0$.